# Ubuntu: setup user-data ssh

Tags: server, 20.04, ssh, raspberrypi

I want to install Ubuntu Server 20.04 on Rpi 4 without monitor, so I have to setup SSH in advance by editing `user-data` file in `system-boot` folder.

Is it possible to setup SSH for user: set public key and disable password by default before the first login to my Pi?

I found one manual [here](https://roboticsbackend.com/install-ubuntu-on-raspberry-pi-without-monitor/) but there is no info how to setup SSH properly in `uaer-data` file:

```
chpasswd:
  expire: true
  list:
  - ubuntu:ubuntu
```

I need help as I can't find any comprehensive example for such purpose, unfortunately. But there are some cloud config examples for virtual box ([1](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_atomic_host/7/html/installation_and_configuration_guide/setting_up_cloud_init), [2](https://serverfault.com/a/922051)), so I don't know if it is valid for my case.

```
users:
  - default
  - name: ubuntu
    ssh-authorized-keys:
      - <your user public key here>
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    groups: sudo
    shell: /bin/bash
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing the typo. As you can see this post is not related to boxes. If you use other version and there is no `user-data` file you can just [create it and then package them into an ISO image](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_atomic_host/7/html/installation_and_configuration_guide/setting_up_cloud_init). Anyway, you probably login into your remote box by password at first, then you setup SSH for using keys only. I want to make it at once in `user-data` file - set my public key and disable password before first connection. If it possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Folks, after several attempts installing Ubuntu w/o monitor (playing with blackbox) the required config was succeeded.

My `user-data` file:

```
users:
  - default
  - name: ubuntu
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    groups: sudo, users, admin
    lock_passwd: true
    ssh_pwauth: True
    ssh_import_id: None
    ssh_authorized_keys:
      - <your user public key here>

#chpasswd:
#  expire: true
#  list:
#  - ubuntu:ubuntu

#ssh_pwauth: true
```

Note that default `chpasswd` and `ssh_pwauth`  are commented out and `ssh_authorized_keys` written with underscores unlike many examples.

So, you have to generate SSH key on your machine and add it to `ssh_authorized_keys` list, that's all. No twitching after first connection is required.

Comment: I just like to add it took me some hours to realize **where that "user_data" file was settled on**. By "***image***" you meant the unmounted SD card itself. But, I can't figure it out what's the point to put the public key of the remote guest there. I already put it in "authorized_keys" file... I keep getting refused connections even from the very own console of the server itself ... (...)

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer did not help me. After some more searching I came across [this post](https://g.masse.me/blog/2020/01/14/HOW-TO-pre-configure-your-Ubuntu-installation-for-a-Raspberry-Pi/):

If you are connected via ethernet this is how the `user-data` file should look: (change this in the image before connecting to the pi)

```
#cloud-config

## Set hostname
hostname: raspberry

## Configure default user
system_info:
  default_user:
    name: pi
    ssh_authorized_keys:
      - ssh-rsa ... user@comment
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

And change `ssh-rsa ... user@comment` to the content of `id_rsa.pub` of the machine where you are connecting from

Of course you can also change the `hostname`  and the `default_user` `name`

After successful login you can set the password for this user like this:

```
sudo -i
passwd pi
```

You will be prompted like this:

```
New password: 
Retype new password:
```

And after that:

```
passwd: password updated successfully
```

And then

```
exit
```

If all that does still not work, try this ["Move your existing Raspberry Pi 4 Ubuntu install from SD card to USB/SSD"](https://medium.com/xster-tech/move-your-existing-raspberry-pi-4-ubuntu-install-from-sd-card-to-usb-ssd-52e99723f07b)