# Why have both ssh_pwauth and lock_passwd?

Tags: server, user-data

I am setting up a raspberry pi with ubuntu server, and configuring the `user-data` file to only use public keys when sshing (for security).  In the docs I see that `ssh_pwauth: true` sets a user account to accept passwords when sshing, while `lock_passwd: true` sets it to *not* accept passwords when sshing.

I have seen a few places online where I am instructed to use both, which seems contradictory.

What is really happening here?  Does one option override the other, or do they actually do slightly different things?

**Edit:**

I am following guidance from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1302840/ubuntu-setup-user-data-ssh), so my `user-data` looks like:

```
users:
  - name: ubuntu
    sudo: ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
    groups: sudo, users, admin
    ssh_pwauth: true
    lock_passwd: true
    ssh_import_id: None
    ssh_authorized_keys:
      - <public key here>
```

with nothing else.

Just to be clear - it is working (I can ssh); my question is what the difference is between these options.  I don't want to leave a security hole anywhere.

Comment: Not sure but do you have a link to the instructions? I can not seem to find one stating both are to be set. Seems to me `lock_passwd` is a per-user setting that prevents logging in (so could be used to lock out 1 user and it also does not have to be `ssh` ) and `ssh_pwauth` seems a global(?) setting that is forcing usage of a password when logging in through ssh. So the two are not mutual exclusive.

Comment: Edited the question to include a link and my current `user-data`.  Does that help?